# Scale object from invisible to visible using ViewPropertyAnimation

Tags: java, xml, xamarin

Is there way to make my object look from invisible to visible using ViewPropertyAnimation?
I want to move it in a position. While my object is moving to this position i want to increase it's size as original one.

```
btn.Animate()
.TranslationX(0)
.TranslationY(-250)
.SetDuration(1000)
.SetInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(4))
.ScaleXBy(0).ScaleX(1);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"><android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Object is moved in right direction but it's size is remain the same.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can first set ScaleX(0), and then use ScaleX(1) to set it to increase the size to the original one by some trigger, for example, click a button.
So the code is like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "Animation", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    FloatingActionButton btn;
    Button btn2;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        btn = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.button1);
        btn2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
        btn2.Click += StartAnimate;
        btn.Animate().SetDuration(0).ScaleX(0);
    }

    private void StartAnimate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn.Animate().SetStartDelay(100).TranslationX(0).TranslationY(-250).SetDuration(1000).SetInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(4)).ScaleX(1);
    }
}
```